# unable to Call Image in Joomla Module

Tags: php, joomla, module

I am working on my first joomla module and stuck with calling an image.
Everything seems to work, I am able to install the module and use it in correct position but when I use is image is missing. 
 Below is the code i have used in helper.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Helper class for Hello World! module
 * 
 * @package    Joomla.Tutorials
 * @subpackage Modules
 * @link http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module
 * @license        GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 * mod_helloworld is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
 * to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
 * is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
 * other free or open source software licenses.
 */
class modpdisplayHelper
{
    /**
     * Retrieves the hello message
     *
     * @param   array  $params An object containing the module parameters
     *
     * @access public
     */    
    public static function getpdisplay($params)
    {
        return <<<HTML
    <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/images/home/product1.jpg" alt="" />
                                            <h2>FREE</h2>
                                            <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Details</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                                <p>Product Details goes Here</p>
                                                <h2>FREE</h2>
                                                <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Details</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
</div>
HTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: try with JURI::base()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$this->baseurl` and `$this->template` in a Joomla module. These will only work in a template file.

Instead, use:

```
<?php
  $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
  $path = JUri::base(true) . '/templates/' . $app->getTemplate();
?>

<img src="<?php echo path; ?>/images/home/product1.jpg" alt="" />
```

To be honest, image that **are not** related to the template, in your case product images, should be placed in:

> media/mod_mymodule/images/

#### Update with final code:

```
public static function getpdisplay($params)
{
    $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
    $path = JUri::base(true) . '/templates/' . $app->getTemplate();
    
    $html = '<div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="' . $path . '/images/home/product1.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>FREE</h2>
                            <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Details</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                <p>Product Details goes Here</p>
                                <h2>FREE</h2>
                                <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Details</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: this image is placed in \templates\mynewtemplate\images\home where    mynewtemplate is the template. One Doubt. Where should I place  code in the helper.php     <?php
  $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
  $path = JUri::base(true) . '/templates/' . $app->getTemplate();
?>

Comment: @creativated_dev - I've updated my answer with the code